# How to output URL of MMC which Resource Type is "External"

Tags: 2013-sp1, multimedia

I'm using Tridion 2013 SP1.
I'd like to put binary files outside Tridion, but to manage it as multimedia components.
When choosing "External" in Resource Type on multimedia component editor, "URL" field appears and can input URL of binary file which is outside Tridion.

For instance, I input following URL.

```
http://image.com/img.jpg
```

However, Tridion handle the URL as following process.

1. Download binary from the URL
2. Publish the binary file

As a result, following a tag is output.

```
<a href="/images/img.jpg">
```

My desirable behaviour is that Tridion doesn't download binary file, but just output the URL and generate following a tag.

```
<a href="http://image.com/img.jpg">
```

I guess one of Default TBBs which is in "Default Finish Action" do that work, but I cannot customize Default TBBs because source code is not distributed.

How is it possible to achieve my goal?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about normal aspx but if you are using DD4T, you can override Binary publisher class "PublishMultimediaComponent" to set the url link without actually adding the item to package so that it never get published as an asset

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you encounter is exactly how External Multimedia Components are supposed to work - we publish them too.

To achieve what you want, you need ECL instead. See [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-9859C89E-3333-4AA1-B4D9-CA5F5163EEB7) for a walk-through.