# SDL Web 8.5 Cloud based BLOB storage for CD

Tags: deployer, azure, s3

In Web 8.5 there is an option to use BLOB storage from S3/Azure to avoid storing the data in the CM DB.  It would seem sensible that the CD side would be able to leverage this single data store instead of having to go through the arduous task of re-deploying the same assets back into S3/Azure.

I can't find anything that indicates otherwise; can someone please advise is this *really* the case?

Thanks
MP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point (8.5) only the CM supports this indeed.

For that same use case you're asking about I'm currently designing/building a solution with ECL instead. The file as stored by the CM is unusable outside of the context of the CM itself, and this was built in 8.5 merely as a way to alleviate DB storage requirements in CM, not as a way to bypass or change how publishing works.

Comment: What a shame. What happens when you publish then, is the image downloaded from the cloud storage and added into the transport package that's sent to Deployer?

Comment: It behaves exactly the same as if the binary was stored in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - for what my opinion is worth, I think that's definitely a big missed opportunity not including at least the 'big 2' cloud storage providers as a deployer persistence option in the core product.

Comment: Also, it also seems a bit of a possible bottleneck; as a customer, if you are persisting both source and published assets in the cloud (using S3 as an example which is notoriously latent, and especially so with the overhead of many small assets) aside from doubling up your storage costs, you could add a heck lot of overall time to your publishing and deployment activities?

Comment: Fair comments. IIRC, it was mostly a question of timing, as the CM team was ready and we decided to push it out. Up to the Product Management team to decide what to do next (I'm not in PM anymore).

Comment: Is there no way you could use custom resolving to avoid adding the binary files themselves but pass the cloud reference instead?

Comment: Came across @rdhaundiyal's [comment here](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14347/how-to-output-url-of-mmc-which-resource-type-is-external) re. DD4T. Seems this could allow you to stop adding the asset to the package but still set a URL link.

Comment: Yup, something like that could work when setting binaries as "external multimedia" - not the same thing as using S3/Azure Blob/File System as Multimedia storage. The latter allows you to store all binaries (and versions) outside of the CM database, and there's a migration script.

Comment: @NunoLinhares How is your ECL based solution coming along?